# Program not working as well - C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

The following code gives me a zero value for 'count' all the time...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 128

int main ()

{
    char mychar , string [SIZE];
    int i;
    int count =0 ;    

    printf ("Please enter your string: \n\n");
    fgets (string, SIZE, stdin);

    printf ("Please enter char to find: ");
    mychar = getchar();

    for (i=0 ; (string[i] == '\0') ; i++ )
        if ( string[i]  == mychar )
            count++;

    printf ("The char %c appears %d times" ,mychar ,count);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: It's hard to answer a question correctly when you change it around without leaving any trace of the original. Your first problem and your second problem has no relation at all.

Comment: @Erik It's true that he shouldn't change the question or the code, but the only difference in the code is the presence/absence of `const`. The basic problem is the same in both cases; I for one had no trouble spotting it.

Comment: @Jim Balter: The problem with doing this is that the accepted answer now answers his original question - which doesn't match the question text. If you stumble across this question later it'll take some reading to figure out the relation in between question, accepted answer and comments.

Comment: @Erik I am of course well aware of that but it isn't relevant -- the original code had two bugs, and the changed code fixed one and left the other unfixed; that's nothing like "no relation at all". My point is that there is nothing hard about finding the bugs in the code, and a good SO response addresses all the issues, not just the one(s) that the OP identifies -- the OP often is a neophyte with poor diagnostic skills. (If you want to argue, I won't bother to respond.)

Comment: @Erik "The problem with doing this" -- You don't have to tell me the problem with doing it when I already said it's true that he shouldn't have changed it -- I said that because I am of course well aware of the problems with it. Sheesh.

Comment: @Jim Balter: Sounded to me like you considered it OK to change the question around - I disagreed.

Comment: And speaking of changing things, it seems that you completely changed your own comment. Perhaps that was to "Make a Point" -- a practice properly frowned on at Wikipedia, which SO could learn a lot from.

Comment: "Sounded to me like you considered it OK to change the question around" -- I don't believe you. I explicitly said that the OP should not have done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
int const count = 0;
```

with

```
int count = 0;
```

Your are trying to change a variable (`count++`) declared `const` which, obviously, is not allowed.

**EDIT:** The answer to your updated question is that you should change the loop condition from `string[i] == '\0'` to `string[i] != '\0'`. This is because the loop runs *while* the condition is true. `string[i] != '\0'` is true for the whole string except the terminating null byte while the opposite is true for `string[i] == '\0'`. Therefore, your original loop didn't run a single time.

Comment: Already tried and it gives me count =0 all the time...maybe count value destroy because of the loop life cycle

Comment: @Adam D: I guess you should change the loop condition from `string[i] == '\0'` to `string[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: @Adam D: The loop runs *until* the condition becomes *false*. `string[i] != '\0'` becomes false when you reach the end of your string while `string[i] == '\0'` is false at any character before the end of your string. Therefore, your original loop didn't run a single time.

Comment: @Adam May I humbly request that, if you don't know the difference between `==` and `!=`, that you stop *answering* questions about C until you have a better mastery of it. I have noticed that nearly all of your answers to C questions are incorrect. I would downvote them all but I would rather not waste my reputation points.

Comment: This "answer" fails badly. The question was already edited to remove `const`, but still contains the bug identified in the *comment* above. The answer should be in the answer text, not in a comment below the answer.

Comment: IMHO it's clearer to say that the loop runs *while* the condition is *true*.

Comment: Note that, if the user entered an empty string (just hit Enter), the OP's loop would count the NUL and then execute undefined behavior by accessing a location beyond the end of the string.

Comment: Oops, actually, it's harder than that to enter an empty string ... just hitting Enter would include the newline.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
int const count =0 ;
```

and this

```
count++;
```

conflicts , value of const variable can't be changed (that is why it is called constant)

Comment: Being more straight-forward, he means, remove the `const` from your int declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change a constant, so `int const count = 0;` can't be modified by `const++;`, to solve it you just have to remove the `const` keyword:

```
 int count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i=0 ; (string[i] == '\0') ; i++ )
        if ( string[i]  == mychar )
            count++;
```

This means run the loop for as long as `string[i] == '\0'`, but `string[i]` can't also be `mychar` (unless `mychar` is `\0`) so you never increment `count`.

I think you meant:

```
for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
   if (string[i]  == mychar)
      count++;
```

Answer (score -3):

Replace `==` with `!=` in `string[i] == '\0'`

Comment: What sort of imbeciles downvoted this **correct** answer, and why? And it was *the first* correct answer, and the accepted "answer" doesn't even contain the answer ... that was added as a comment! SO can be so disappointing sometimes.